# JAMV returns false date

Tags: java, jamvm

Im running jamvm on a PLC, but the virtual machine returns not the system time but always a false date.

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()
```

I have also checked the system time and it's set correctly.
For example today 11.08 it returns 2016-07-27 20:30:42.992

Comment: What's a "PLC"? And what do these false dates look like? How bad are they? Wrong day? Wrong year? What's your operating system? etc.

Comment: its a Programmable logic controller, basically  a embedded syytem with a real time linux it returns the correct time but wrong day. for example 2016-07-27 20:30:42.992 but the it returns the wrong day it must be 2016-08-10